# How to stop a MediaPlayer when I go to next activity in Android studio

Tags: android

```
public class momtahina5 extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "momtahina5";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_momtahina5);

    Log.d(TAG,"onCreate: Starting.");


    Button gotobakara201 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gotobakara201);
    Button backtobakara286 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backtobakara286);


    gotobakara201.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked btngotobakara201");
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(momtahina5.this,bakara201.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(momtahina5.this,R.raw.mumfive);
            mp.start();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: onpause stop it onpause

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is **Release** media player when activity is finished or destroyed.

below code will demonstrate you.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mp != null) {
        mp.stop();
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: mp.release() ; add this too

Comment: Thank you, but the music does not stop, it continue on next activity.

Comment: @user7786695, You need to call `finish()` or else put the code into the `onPause()` method.

Answer (score 0):

override the 'onPause()' method of the current Activity and in that do this:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mp != null) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
}
```

And also you want to make the MediaPlayer object as a class variable.

*Edit: It would be better to use the onPause() method instead of the onDestroy() method. When you move to another activity, the previous activity is not immediately destroyed. Refer to [Android activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your  comments. I tried it, but the music does not stop, it continue on next activity.

Comment: It stop, but when I go to next screen, this screen's audio not playing.

Comment: Wasn't that the goal?